# How to prevent an imageview to be "pushed" outside the screen by a textview with variable dimensions?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In a constraint layout, I have a textview, with an imageview next to it:
[image]

But sometimes the text in the textview can be very long and sometimes span more than one line. In these cases, the imageview get pushed outside the view:
[image]

Even addind a constraint between the imageview and the view container, the imageview gets pushed outside the view.

The goal is to always have the image right next to the text and if it grows, the image starts getting pushed to the side as long is not going outside the view. When it touches the boundaries of the view, it should stay there while the text wraps to the next line.

This code block just shows the case of the second picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:text="This is a cat with a lot more text next to it so pay attention  "/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[3]"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried usgin barriers and guidelines, but they really do not serve for this case. The textview needs to be wrap_content since its size is variable and it is preferable to use constraint layout, that's why I did not used another one. Chains also did not work here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a packed chain with a bias of 0 to make it start-aligned and then set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for both views so that their constraints are respected when wrapping content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Text goes here"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: With constraint layout 2.1.0 instead of app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" I had to use app:layout_constrainedWidth="wrap_content_constrained" for the TextView

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting textview's `wrap_content`. Doing so will let the textview decide its own width, ignoring layout constraints such as margins.

You need to set width to `0dp` which is interpreted as `match_constraint` in constraint layout, it allows the layout to decide textview's width which means that textview will be given as much width as necessary after margins and other layout constraints are applied.

Now to your desired effect, first remove all constraints from both views. Select both of them, then right click and select chain option from the options menu. Then Pack them horizontally. This would form a chain.
**Why do we need chain?**
Because you want the imageview to right of textview and textview to left of image view, this kind of two way constraint cannot be added because TextView won't draw till imageview is drawn and imageview is waiting for textview to draw.
Chain will help you tackle this problem.

Comment: thanks for the response! In this case the property layout_constrainedWidth was what I was lacking. In fact I needed the chain, but just it was not enough.

Comment: layout_constrainedWidth and setting layout_width to 0dp do the same thing so both answers are same, I was typing on phone so it was posted a little late but nevertheless, glad it works :)